# HTML weird ReferenceError while trying to make a mouse tracker

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm making a project where i need a mouse tracker, so this is a super simple version i found online but it gives an error (while working). On my mozilla it's actually updating as i move around the mouse on the site, but for some reason it spawns the "e is not defined" error instead of posting the coordinates

```
<svg id='canvas' onmousemove="setMousePosition(e)">
</svg>

<script>
    function setMousePosition(e) {
        var x = e.clientX;
        var y = e.clientY;
        console.log("x coord" + x + "y coord" + y);
    }
</script>
```

Which gives the error

> "ReferenceError: e is not defined"

, which i find super weird... Using mozilla firefox 54'

EDIT: chrome gives

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined
>       at SVGSVGElement.onmousemove (mainhtml.html:24)"

, so im thinking it's connected to the SVG element..?

EDITEDIT: found a workaround by having an empty div covering the svg element which seems to be bugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have confused how an event handler supplied as a code snippet in HTML is compiled into a function object with how you would write a  function added as an event handler to an object in the DOM.

```
    <svg id='canvas' onmousemove="setMousePosition(e)">
    </svg>
```

compiles the code snippet into a function object taking an event parameter

```
function ( event) {
     setMousePosition(e);
}
```

which lacks a definition of e. The obvious fix is to write

```
    <svg id='canvas' onmousemove="setMousePosition(event)">
    </svg>
```

This can work but is not recommended because of historic browser differences and the acceptability of placing event handlers within HTML code. So one solution, to execute when the document is ready, is to add a handler to the SVG HTML element.

```
     document.getElementById( 'canvas').addEventListener( "mousemove", setMousePosition);
```

as in this example

```js
function setMousePosition(e) {
    var x = e.clientX;
    var y = e.clientY;
    console.log("x coord " + x + " y coord " + y);
}
document.getElementById("canvas").addEventListener("mousemove", setMousePosition);
```

```html
<svg id="canvas" height=200 width=400 style="border: thin solid blue">
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Event object in an intrinsic event handler function is assigned to a variable named `event` not `e`.

```
onmousemove="setMousePosition(event)"
```

In general, it is prefered to add event listeners using JavaScript, not HTML:

```
document.querySelector("svg").addEventListener("mousemove", setMousePosition);
```

The function passed to `addEventListener` will receive the event object as the first argument.

The 90s style intrinsic event attributes do something akin to:

```
    document.querySelector("svg").addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) { /* attribute value here */ });
```

Answer (score -2):

as far I know currently you can't get mouse position inside svg, but here alternative solution, wrap it in div

```js
function setMousePosition(e) {
  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;
  document.getElementById('position').innerHTML = ("Position: x coord: " + x + " / y coord: " + y);
}
```

```css
#svg-containe {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

#canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  border: 1px dashed #bbb;
}
```

```html
<div id="svg-container" onmousemove="setMousePosition(event)">
  <svg id='canvas'></svg>
</div>
<p id="position">
</p>
```

Comment: That gets the position of the SVG element, not of the mouse pointer.